# strange indexing mechanism of pandas.read_csv function with chunksize option

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Due to the huge data size, we used pandas to process data, but a very strange phenomenon occurred. The pseudo code looks like this:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(IN_FILE, chunksize = 1000, engine='c')
for chunk in reader:
    result = []
    for line in chunk.tolist():
         temp = complicated_process(chunk)  # this involves a very complicated processing, so here is just a simplified version
         result.append(temp)
    chunk['new_series'] = pd.series(result)
    chunk.to_csv(OUT_TILE, index=False, mode='a')
```

We can confirm each loop of result is not empty. But only in the first time of the loop, line `chunk['new_series'] = pd.series(result)` has result, the rest are empty. Therefore, only the first chunk of the output contains new_series, the rest are empty.

Did we miss anything here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare `result` above your loop, otherwise you are just re-initializing it with each chunk.

```
result = []
for chunk in reader:
    ...
```

You previous method is functionally equivalent to:

```
for chunk in reader:
    del result  # because it is being re-assigned on the following line.
    result = []
    result.append(something)
print(result)  # Only shows result from last chunk in reader (the last loop).
```

Also, I would recommend:

```
chunk = chunk.assign(new_series=result)  # Instead of `chunk['new_series'] = pd.series(result)`.
```

I am assuming you are doing something with the `line` variable in your `for loop`, even though it is not used in your example above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, you suggestion worked. But I don't understand why moving result=[] outside works. This is very awkward to me. Can you elaborate a bit? Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But this is not exactly what caused the problem. When we tracked the indexing of each chunk, I found that they are not individual. We supposed that each chunk would start the index from 0, but in reality, it is NOT. The index of each chunk is a subset of the whole CSV in this situation, so their index derives from the CSV. This is what caused the problem. In the above example, the `pandas.to_csv` writes only the result of the first chunk, instead of the last chunk. But I still would thank for your inspiration; otherwise, I really didn't know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you use my `chunk = chunk.assign(new_series=result)` recommendation? I don't think you would have had this issue with it.

Comment: I did, and still had the problem. When I reindexed the chunk, and use your `assign` function, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be this:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(IN_FILE, chunksize = 1000, engine='c')
for chunk in reader:
    result = []
    for line in chunk.tolist():
        temp = complicated_process(chunk)  # this involves a very complicated processing, so here is just a simplified version
        result.append(temp)
    new_chunk = chunk.reset_index()
    new_chunk = new_chunk.assign(new_series=result)
    new_chunk.to_csv(OUT_TILE, index=False, mode='a')
```

Notice: the index of each chunk is not individual, but is derived the whole file. If we append a new series from each loop, the chunk will inherit the index from the whole file. Therefore, the index of each chunk and the new series does not match.

The solution by @Alexander works, but the `result` might become huge, so it will occupy too much memory.

The new solution here will reset index for each chunk by doing `new_chunk = chunk.reset_index()`, and `result` will be reset within each loop. This saves a lot of memory.